# Why save objects on files in serialization?

Tags: java

I think i am little bit confused on this part . As Why we use files in serialization in order to store our save objects that we read later, why dont we just skip serialization and store it into database and read it from there. Aint this is similar

Comment: Why do *you* (or the code you are talking about) use files on serialization? And why do *you* (or the code you are talking about) serialize data when/before using a database? In any case, databases and simple serialized objects are *different* things with different use-cases.

Comment: A database may be overkill for storing simple/trivial data.

Comment: What happens if you don't have a database handy, or want to be able to zip/email/whatever the file? And more fundamentally, what do you think a database is doing, if not saving the serialized bytes in a file (or probably more accurately, in a portion of a file)?